# How is Facebook formatting the JSON output from their API when viewed in the browser?

Tags: json, facebook, api

When accessing the Facebook graph through a browser, for example on:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/1633633315
```

I get some nicely formatted JSON like this:

```
{
   "id": "1633633315",
   "name": "Karat Noppakoon",
   "first_name": "Karat",
   "last_name": "Noppakoon",
   "gender": "female",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "username": "Karat.Noppakoon"
}
```

While accessing a lot of other API's, like Flickr for example, the output will not be formatted at all:

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":543882,"perpage":10,"total":"5438811","photo":[{"id":"3346088899","owner":"35260559@N03","secret":"e2a2e20a0a","server":"3366","farm":4,"title":"web development","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"url_o":"https:\/\/farm4.staticflickr.com\/3366\/3346088899_b6fcda66f5_o.jpg","height_o":"309","width_o":"386","url_m":"https:\/\/farm4.staticflickr.com\/3366\/3346088899_e2a2e20a0a.jpg","height_m":"309","width_m":"386"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hidden \r \n ([return, newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) characters in the JSON from Facebook. It's pointless, takes up *slightly* more space as is only useful for readability. The other APIs don't do this. It makes no difference to how the string will be parsed.

EDIT: Please see screenshot from Notepad++ set to show hidden/invisible characters.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 

I think it makes some sense though, the improved readability is quite nice while exploring and developing for an API.

Comment: It should be an option that can be enabled in sandbox/developer mode, and should be disabled by default or in a production environment.

Comment: Interesting! Can you show some code how is it done? I use `PHP` to create web service, and I create objects with `stdClass`

Comment: When outputting a string to the browser in PHP, you'd use double quotes and then \r\n will work for you. :) eg. echo "My first line\r\nMy second line."; Note, this will new line the source only, a HTML break would be required to break it onto a new line in the DOM.